# How count a column from a tableB where tableA.y = TableB.y laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to count number of courses and questions of each modules.
When I try it with this code below, it displays the counting of all questions

```
 //$data = DB::table('module')->orderBy('idmodule', 'desc')->paginate(5);
 $data = DB::table('module')
    ->leftJoin('cours', 'module.idmodule', '=', 'cours.id_module')
    ->leftJoin('question', 'cours.id_cours', '=', 'question.id_cours')
    ->select('module.*', 'cours.*',DB::raw("count(cours.id_module) as cours"),DB::raw("count(question.id_cours) as quest"))
    ->groupBy('module.idmodule')
    ->get();

 $id = Auth::id();
 return view('admin.modules',compact('data'))>with('profile',profile::find($id));
```

Comment: Can you show some examples of the expected output based on your data? I'm not sure I understand which count you want out.

Comment: can you try `->toSql()` to see it raw from sql query. we can debug more from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare the relation between `Module`->`Cour` and  `Module`->`Question`, you can simply do

```
$modules = Modules::withCount(['cours', 'questions'])->get();
```

Module.php :

```
public function cours()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Cour::class, 'id_module', 'idmodule');
}

public function questions()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Question::class, Cour::class, 'id_module', 'id_cours', 'idmodule', 'id_cours');
}
```

Comment: @Souheib dont forget to set your question as answered.